# Hide location bar from firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In my add-on I have an HTML page that gets displayed upon install/update. Firefox obviously shows the chrome:// URI of the page, and I was trying to figure out how to prevent that from happening (just for aesthetic reasons, mind you...).

I know that some add-ons are able to hide the location bar on certain tabs/pages: how do they do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox has a list with URLs where it hides the location bar: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/f41df039db03/browser/base/content/browser.js#l4146. If you have a browser overlay you should be able to add your own URL to that list:

```
if (typeof XULBrowserWindow == "object" && XULBrowserWindow.inContentWhitelist instanceof Array)
  XULBrowserWindow.inContentWhitelist.push("chrome://...");
```

The checks are meant to ensure that you don't do anything wrong if the Firefox code changes in some future version.

Comment: If `XULBrowserWindow` is undefined, you can get a reference to it by using the window mediator service: `Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm"); const XULBrowserWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').XULBrowserWindow;`