# Open new xul tab without showing the address (like google chrome)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, xul

is it possible to open a xul page (chrome://myext/content/page.xul) with a blank address page?

I want to have a xul page in a new tab to collect some information to my extension, but i wanted to hide the chrome address.

in chrome, some extension pages are shown without an address, like follows:

Evernote Clearly:
[image: Evernote Clearly with no address]

Contextinator:

[image: Contextinator with no address]

Is it possible on firefox to open the chrome://myext/content/page.xul without showing this address on the address bar?

Comment: In Chrome, all URLs are hidden. This is not intended, but a bug which has been fixed recently - see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox, this is usually done by hiding browser chrome.

If you're using [addon-sdk](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/), this can be accomplished by including the [addon-page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/addon-page.html) like so:

```
require("sdk/addon-page");
```

When not using addon-sdk (ie, XUL based extension), then you might need to look into `hideChromeForLocation()` and `inContentWhitelist` members of [XULBrowser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULBrowserWindow). Hiding browser chrome is [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Hiding_browser_chrome) and the source code for the members can be found in *browser.js*: [hideChromeForLocation](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js#3974), [inContentWhitelist](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js#3596).

Note: XULBrowserWindow itself is a property of window.

```
var {XULBrowserWindow}=window;
```

An example of a location with hidden chrome is the Addon Manager (*about:addons*), which hides the navigation bar when viewing that particular location.

Comment: Thanks @jongo45. My extension is a XUL based one, so i researched how to add my chrome page to the inContentWhitelist array and found this other answer: [Hide location bar from firefox add-on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7147199/1385896). I did the same thing and it works perfectly.